# Counting the number of inputs provided by user

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, conditional-statements, git-bash

Description: I have a script that begins with a warning/question posed to user. I need the user to answe with yes/y or no/n.

Issue: Though I have a conditional to make sure the user provides one of the following answers presented above I also need to make that only ONE input is provided by the user. I have attempted using

`[ "$#" -eq 1 ]` or `[ $# -eq 1 ]` neither of these coniditionals seems to work to solve the problem

here is what I have thus far:...

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Descritpion: some Windows OS script
#
# 

printf "(!)WARNING(!): 1. The this program is ONLY compatible with Windows operating systems. "
printf "2. You will NEED to be logged in as an ADMIN in order to fully make use of the '*****' script.\n" 
printf "Would you like to continue? yes or no (y/n): "

#would it be cleaner to use "case" rather than a "while" w/ multiple conditionals? (01.19.2020)
read opt

while (true)
do
        if [ $opt == yes ] || [ $opt == y ]
        then
                printf "continue. \n"
                break

        elif [ $opt == no ] || [ $opt == n ]
        then
                printf "OK, exiting the script! \n"
                exit 0

        #elif [ "$#" -ne 1 ]
        #then
        #       "Too many arguments have been provided, please try again. \n"
        #       read opt
        else
                printf "The opition you provided is not recognized, please try again. \n"
                read opt
        fi
done
```

Comment: `only ONE input is provided by the use` - please give an example and what should happen. What do you mean by "ONE input"? What is a "two input"?

Answer (score 0):

Not the ideal solution, but it includes an explanation of why $# is not working as you expect:

$# returns the number of arguments passed to a function. You have read 'opt' in as a user input - not the arguments to the function.

One solution could be to wrap your infinite while loop inside a function, and then pass $opt into it. It would then be the argument(s) to your function and you could use $# to count how many there are.
For details of the workings of many built-in functions in bash, you could try:

```
man bash
```

but I accept that there is a *lot* of information in there. You can search for the relevant words, normally using "/{searchstring}" (but you will probably need to "escape" the special characters, in this case: "/\$\#")

Comment: As @Diego says, read has various options - using "-a" to ask it to read into an array will help you. You could then use "parameter expansion" (look for that section in the bash manual page). Here is a little script that I just put together after a bit more reading of the man page:

    #!/bin/bash
    declare -a opt
    read -a opt
    echo "opt: ${opt}, count: ${#opt[*]}"

When I run this script, I can enter:

    test two three

and it responds with:

    opt: test, count: 3

Comment: Sorry, that was my first SE comment, and I'm struggling with the formatting and can no longer edit it (after 5 minutes). I thought I had the <pre> <code> block, but I must have misunderstood. The important part of the script above is the `read -a opt` line and the `echo "opt: ${opt}, count: ${#opt[*]}"` line. The last part of that is the parameter expansion, replacing the opt array with the number of elements currently in the array.

Thanks for the nudge @Diego. I didn't comment on your answer, because I'm not yet able to... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `read` options

> read: read [-ers] [-u fd] [-t timeout] [-p prompt] [-a array] [-n nchars] [-d delim] [name ...]
>
> One line is read from the standard input, or from file descriptor FD if the
>       -u option is supplied, and the first word is assigned to the first NAME,
>       the second word to the second NAME, and so on, with leftover words assigned
>       to the last NAME.  Only the characters found in $IFS are recognized as word
>       delimiters.  If no NAMEs are supplied, the line read is stored in the REPLY
>       variable.  If the -r option is given, this signifies `raw' input, and
>       backslash escaping is disabled.  The -d option causes read to continue
>       until the first character of DELIM is read, rather than newline.  If the -p
>       option is supplied, the string PROMPT is output without a trailing newline
>       before attempting to read.  If -a is supplied, the words read are assigned
>       to sequential indices of ARRAY, starting at zero.  If -e is supplied and
>       the shell is interactive, readline is used to obtain the line.  If -n is
>       supplied with a non-zero NCHARS argument, read returns after NCHARS
>       characters have been read.  The -s option causes input coming from a
>       terminal to not be echoed.

you would be able to simplify your script using some of them.

Answer (score 0):

Read the input and parse it exactly. Decide, if you want to ignore spaces or not. You could even use a regex to make the input formatted as exactly as you want.

1. `while (true)` is an unnecessary use of subshell. Just `while true`.
2. `if [ $opt == yes ]` will not work if `opt` contains whitespaces, for example user inputs `y e s`. It will exit with a nonzero exit status and print an error message on standard error stream. As a rule, always quote your variable expansions. Always `"$opt"`, never `$opt`. This is most probably the error you are asking for fixing.
3. Also the `==` is a bash extension. Use `=` for string comparison.
4. Cosmetics: `[ $opt == yes ] || [ $opt == y ]` unnecessary runs two processes in case the first one fails. Just run one process `[ "$opt" = yes -o "$opt" = y ]`. But the first one may be just more clear.
5. `read opt` ignores leading and trailing whitespaces and removes the `\` slashes. Use `IFS= read -r opt` to read the whole line exactly as it is.
6. Use shellcheck.net to check your scripts.
7. The `$#` is the number of arguments passed to the script. It is unrelated to what `read` does. `read` saves the input to the variable.

So:

```
while true; do
   if ! IFS= read -r opt; then
      echo "ERROR: END OF INPUT!" >&2
      exit 2
   fi
   case "$opt" in
   y|yes) printf 'continue. \n'; break; ;;
   n|no) printf 'OK, exiting the script! \n'; exit 1; ;;
   *) printf 'The opition you provided is not recognized, please try again. \n'; ;;
   esac
done
```